# has many through, dependent destroy issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a few issues with dependent destroy functionality.
The models are as follows.

Company.rb

```
has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :company_users, dependent: :destroy
```

CompanyUser.rb

```
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :user
```

User.rb

```
has_one :company_user, dependent: :destroy
has_one :company, through: :company_user
```

When i delete a company, it needs to delete the company user and ALSO THE USER.

Currently it is deleting only the company user. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Why would you want to delete the user?

If the user is associated with any other company there will be a problem

Comment: If the case is that a user will be associated with only one company I think you should go with `company has_many users` you don't need through association in this case

Comment: The user is related to only one company. The scenario is that when a company is deleted, all the associated users should also be deleted.

Comment: Read the second comment then

Comment: @prajeesh are per your requirement the association should be like this `user belongs to company, company has many users`

Comment: user belongs to company, company has many users doesnt seem to work

Comment: What is the issue when you use Vishal's suggestion?

Comment: Modified the associations as follows. user belongs to company. user has_one company_user, dependent: :destroy. company has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy. company has_many :users, dependent: :destroy.    still getting deleted only from company and company users.

Comment: I would argue that your `CompanyUser` model is useless if a user belongs to a company directly. Such join models are usually only needed in has_and_belongs_to_many situations. What's the purpose of that model in your application?

Comment: the above mentioned relationship should have has_and_belongs_to_many association

Comment: I think first thing you need to do is, mention the clear requirements. Like, User can associate with multiple companies or not? If yes, can they be associated with multiple companies at the same time or they have joining&leaving dates associated? Also, if they can associate to multiple companies, you should not remove the user completely with deletion of company. If users can associate with only one company then you should change your association to be one to many.

Answer (score 3):

This will work and find the comments inline for changes done

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, through: :company_users #removed dependent destroy
    has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy 
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :company_user
    has_one :company, through: :company_user
end

class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy #added dependent destroy
end
```

Logs

```
DELETE FROM "company_users" WHERE "company_users"."id" = ?[0m  [["id", 4]]
DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?[0m  [["id", 4]]
DELETE FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = ?  [["id", 4]]
```

Comment: This works but has one issue. When a user is deleted, corresponding company user should also be deleted. That is why i had added has_one :company_user, dependent: :destroy . But this will railse the 'Stack Level too deep'  error.  Any idea on how to fix this?